# If we delete the non-primes from $e$, is the resulting number transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

If we eliminate the non-prime single-digit numbers from $e$, and then smash the remaining numbers together to make a new number, is it transcendental?

Comment: 2.722235327735227757273557...

Comment: What do you mean by delete the non-prime numbers?  Do you mean specifically removing $\{1,4,6,8,9\}$ from the decimal expansion, or every non-prime?  What if after doing this once there are more non-primes (because you're considering multiple-digit primes potentially), do you repeat it again?

Comment: Just single digit primes, like in the first comment.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that we know the answer to this since we don't know whether e is normal or not.

Comment: Thank you. Why is normal or not important to answering the question?

Comment: Have you any reason for asking this question?  In particular, have you any reason for supposing that it is answerable, given the current state of the subject?

Comment: Whether a number is transcendental does not depend upon the base in which it is expressed (base 2, base 10, etc.).  In this regard, there is nothing special about representing $e$ in base 10 (as assumed by the OP).  If we ask the question assuming a different base (e.g., base 2), it is obvious that the resulting number is *not* transcendental.

Comment: What if we don't move them, we just replace the non-prime single digits with single digit primes, whatever you choose.

Comment: The reason I am asking is because I am looking for transcendental numbers.

Comment: There is no way any human could answer this question at this point in time. Not sure why you think we could. Surely you can find a better recipe for creating transcendental numbers.

Comment: Good to know! I honestly had no idea if there was an answer. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: If you merely wish to generate transcendental numbers, look up the Gelfond-Schneider Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not a direct answer to the posed question, if the goal is to generate transcendental numbers (as the OP expressed in a comment), then exploit the [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem):

- If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic numbers, with $\alpha \ne 0$
  and $\alpha \ne 1$ and $\beta \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $\alpha^\beta$ is
  transcendental.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't answer the question, but it does answer the comments. And the comments show there is no answer to the question. I like your suggestion to answering the ultimate question: where are all the transcendental numbers? But I guess in my fantasy they come from transcendental numbers.

Comment: Just as integers come from integers... and rationals come from rationals... and imaginaries come from imaginaries...  (Off the subject:  I see you're a painter.  I lecture in art museums all over the world.)

Comment: Awesome! I love that.